# How does the browser know what to render if it is not in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs

I want to copy an ExtJS-generated form to another window (for printing), and keep the form values. The same procedure already works for grids. But when trying to copy the DOM tree of a form into another window, the form values are lost (everything else is kept, only the values from the fields are missing).

So now I am trying to figure out how the browser knows which value to render into which field, since the value does not show up in the markup.

Maybe I am getting old, but when I started development, every value of an input field was stored in the DOM like this:

```
<input type="text" value="VALUE">
```

I already copied the whole page's DOM from the browser console into a text editor and searched for form values, but they are not there, so I am 100% certain there's nothing hidden somewhere outside the formpanel, that is aligned to the correct position with absolute positioning or anything.

So, how does the browser know what to render if it is not in the DOM?

Comment: Values entered into input fields by the user have never been reflected by the `value` content attribute. How did you copy the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question - all data stored in the JS code of ExtJS component (JS object) and DOM is just its graphcial representation that updates when needed.

For example, form (component) is an object that contains all the necessary information, including DOM wich is not base of the component, but only a graphical representation. When entering data we change component and only then, if necessary, its graphical representation. Thus, if I create simple form like in [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12dj) and set form item `value: 'myName'`, in this DOM I can find `value` property of `input`

```
<input id="textfield-1010-inputEl" data-ref="inputEl" type="text" size="1" name="name" value="myName" role="textbox" aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-text-default " autocomplete="off" data-componentid="textfield-1010">
```

but if I change its value with

```
myFormPanel.down('[name=name]').setValue(Math.random());
```

`value` property of `input` will not be updated and form item componet will.

*P.S. If you want to know exactly how browser render page content, then its question about browser engines and how they work with JS, HTML, etc. and you have to read articles [like this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#The_render_tree_relation_to_the_DOM_tree).*